# multiple process to run at the same time

Tags: perl

I am using perl script to execute one script which should execute 10 different processes at the same time. my requirement is:
1. It will first extract each line from atext file(having 10 lines with one word on each line)
2. using this line to exacute one script app.exe for all those names.
3. execute each thread which should execute at the same time.

In order to achieve this i have written below piece of code. However i could see the in the task manager only one process is running at a time. But i need all the 10 process should run simultaneously. Can anyone please help me on this?

```
use Thread; 
$file='input.txt'; 
open(INFO, $file) or die("Could not open file."); 
$count = 0; 
foreach $line (<INFO>) { $huh = Thread->new(\&thread1); 
print "Waiting for thread now\n"; 
$stuff = $huh->join(); 
sub thread1 { print "$line"; 
'QueryStores.exe "UPDATE OPTIONS_STR SET OPT_VALUE = 0 WHERE OPT_ID = 16005" /S:$line'    
return 1;} } close(INFO);
```

Comment: Here is my code

use Thread;
$file='input.txt';
open(INFO, $file) or die("Could not open  file.");
$count = 0; 
foreach $line (<INFO>)  
 {   
$huh = Thread->new(\&thread1);
print "Waiting for thread now\n";
$stuff = $huh->join();
sub thread1 {
        print "$line";
'QueryStores.exe "UPDATE OPTIONS_STR SET OPT_VALUE = 0 WHERE OPT_ID = 16005" /S:$line'
   return 1;}   
    }
close(INFO);

Comment: The code is not very readable can you use stackoverflow guide to post code ?. You might want to use ForkManager to control number of parallel threads that can be run simultaneously http://search.cpan.org/~dlux/Parallel-ForkManager-0.7.5/ForkManager.pm

Comment: Keep in mind the threads don't necessarily print right when you say print.

Comment: @Eric Fossum, 1) Buffering has nothing to do with threads. 2) Since the code is printing to a terminal tied to STDOUT, and since the strings being printed end with a newline, no buffering is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reading your code and the problem seems to be that your thread is waiting to be joined (which is blocking) before next loop iters. Task Manager doesn't show threads (only proceses).  Try [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to see the threads (I haven't personally used but looks like it can do the job)

Your code should be something like this

```
#!/bin/perl 

use warnings;
use strict;

use Thread;

my @list = qw(abc1 abc2 abc3 abc4 abc5);
my @threadlist = ();

for my $lst (@list) {
  my $t = Thread->new(\&thread_exec , $lst);
  print "Wating for thread for $lst\n";
  push @threadlist, $t;
}

for my $thd (@threadlist) {
  print "Wating for thread to join\n";
  $thd->join;
}

sub thread_exec {
  my $info = shift;
  print "INFO = $info\n";
}
```

Which outputs something like this [you can see that threads are running in parallel]

```
$~/Documents/dummy.pl 
Wating for thread for abc1
Wating for thread for abc2
Wating for thread for abc3
Wating for thread for abc4
Wating for thread for abc5
Wating for thread to join
INFO = abc2
INFO = abc5
INFO = abc1
Wating for thread to join
Wating for thread to join
INFO = abc4
INFO = abc3
Wating for thread to join
Wating for thread to join
```

On the other hand - putting join in same for loop (like you have done produces a serialised execution of thread like this)

```
$~/Documents/dummy.pl 
Wating for thread for abc1
INFO = abc1
Wating for thread for abc2
INFO = abc2
Wating for thread for abc3
INFO = abc3
Wating for thread for abc4
INFO = abc4
Wating for thread for abc5
INFO = abc5
```

Comment: Seems like there is no such requirement to limit number of threads. The asker simply says s/he has a file with 10 lines each of which should spawn a new thread in parallel - a simple loop would suffice

Answer (score 4):

1. You are creating threads, not processes.
2. Threads don't show up in Task Manager, so I'm not sure how you can manage to have used the Task Manage to determine that only one is running at a time.
3. You are correct that only one of the threads you create is running at a time, since you wait for the thread you've just created to end (`->join`) before you create another one.

```
use threads;
use Thread::Queue 1.03 qw( );

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 10;

sub worker {
   my ($job) = @_;
   system('QueryStores "UPDATE OPTIONS_STR SET OPT_VALUE = 0 WHERE OPT_ID = 16005" /S:'.$job);
   if    ($? == -1)  { warn("Can't start child $job: $!\n"); } 
   elsif ($? >> 8)   { warn("Child $job returned error ".($? >> 8)."\n"); } 
   elsif ($? & 0x7F) { warn("Child $job killed by signal ".($? & 0x7F)."\n"); } 
}

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
for (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
    async {
        while (defined(my $job = $q->dequeue())) {
           worker($job);
        }
    };
}

while (<>) {
   chomp;
   $q->enqueue($_);
}

$q->end();
$_->join() for threads->list();
```

Comment: Thanks Ikegami.. i have used your below piece of code in the below format. However am not getting any output..

Comment: use constant NUM_WORKERS => 10;
sub worker {
   my ($job) = @_;
  'QueryStores.exe "UPDATE OPTIONS_STR SET OPT_VALUE = 0 WHERE OPT_ID = 16005" /S:$line'}
$file='input.txt';
open(INFO, $file) or die("Could not open  file.");
$count = 0; 
foreach $line (<INFO>)  
{   my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
for (1..10) {    async {
        while (defined(my $job = $q->dequeue())) {
           worker($job);
        }    }; }
while (<>) {   chomp;   $q->enqueue($_);}
$q->end();
$_->join() for threads->list();    }close(INFO);

Comment: Why you'd add all that stuff? Just add what you want to do in each thread to `worker`

Comment: @sputnick, I've heard "slow" or "memory hog" by people who use them incorrectly, but I've never heard unreliable.